# Join and rename data frame based on matching columns in another data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have something like the IRIS dataset and I want to change the names of the data. I have the names saved in a separate data frame such as:

```
     old_names    new_names
1 Sepal.Length Sepal_Length
2  Sepal.Width  Sepal_Width
3 Petal.Length Petal_Length
4  Petal.Width  Petal_Width
5      Species      Species
```

So, I want to replace the `iris` dataset with the "`new_names`" data in the data frame by matching the column `col_names` with the `iris` data frame column names.

Expected output (but not using `sub` or similar to get the result:

```
> names(iris) <- sub("\\.", "_", names(iris))
> iris
    Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
```

Question: use some `left_join` type matching to match the columns up with the dataframe and then rename another data frame based on the matches.

Code and data:

```
iris

cols = colnames(iris)
data.frame(
  old_names = names(iris),
  new_names = sub("\\.", "_", cols)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename using a named vector and `any_of()`. The use of `any_of` is to avoid errors if your dictionary data contains names that don't exist in the data.

```r
iris %>%
  rename(any_of(tibble::deframe(dict[2:1])))

#     Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width    Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
```

where `dict` is

```r
dict <- data.frame(
  old_names = names(iris),
  new_names = sub("\\.", "_", cols)
)
```

---

An alternative is using `rename_with` and `match`:

```r
iris %>%
  rename_with(~ dict$new_names[match(.x, dict$old_names)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution with `match`.
In the data creation code below I shuffle the names data.frame to make it more obvious that it works.

```r
set.seed(20230221)
cols <- names(iris)
dfnames <- data.frame(
  old_names = names(iris),
  new_names = sub("\\.", "_", cols))
dfnames <- dfnames[sample(nrow(dfnames)),]
dfnames
#>      old_names    new_names
#> 4  Petal.Width  Petal_Width
#> 5      Species      Species
#> 1 Sepal.Length Sepal_Length
#> 2  Sepal.Width  Sepal_Width
#> 3 Petal.Length Petal_Length

i <- match(cols, dfnames$old_names)
dfnames$new_names[i]
#> [1] "Sepal_Length" "Sepal_Width"  "Petal_Length" "Petal_Width"  "Species"

names(iris) <- dfnames$new_names[i]
head(iris)
#>   Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A one-liner, without the index `i` is

```
names(iris) <- dfnames$new_names[match(cols, dfnames$old_names)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use match by name of a vector like.

```
rosetta <- setNames(sub("\\.", "_", names(iris)), names(iris))
rosetta
#  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width   Petal.Length    Petal.Width        Species 
#"Sepal_Length"  "Sepal_Width" "Petal_Length"  "Petal_Width"      "Species" 

names(iris) <- rosetta[names(iris)]

head(iris)
#  Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score -2):

use `tidyverse` or `dplyr` package

```
df <- data.frame(NAMES = names(iris))

df <- df %>% mutate(NEW_NAMES = str_replace(NAMES, '\\.','_'))

names(iris) <- df$NEW_NAMES
```

This should work!